In rust and cargo, is it possible to apply rustfmt on doctest code?
Here is an example:
//!   
//! example:
//!  
//!```
//!
//!         use nalgebra::{Quaternion, UnitQuaternion, Vector3};
//! // use crate::naive_cf::NaiveCF;
//!
//! let acc = Vector3::new(3.64637947, 5.30298471, 6.84866046);
//!
//!         let rotation = UnitQuaternion::from_quaternion(Quaternion::new(
//!             0.60163784,
//!             -0.0844770521,
//!            0.269781291,
//!            -0.614157497,
//!        ));
//!
//! let v = NaiveCF::new();
//!        // let v = NaiveCF::get_correction_verified(&acc, &rotation);
//! ```

use crate::{ARGlasses, Error, Fusion, GlassesEvent};
use nalgebra::{Quaternion, UnitQuaternion, Vector3};

...

obviously it is poorly formatted, indentations under the example are all wrong.
I tried to format them automatically with the following rustfmt settings:
format_code_in_doc_comments = true
format_macro_matchers = true
group_imports = "StdExternalCrate"
hex_literal_case = "Lower"
imports_granularity = "Module"
newline_style = "Unix"
normalize_comments = true
normalize_doc_attributes = true
use_field_init_shorthand = true
use_try_shorthand = true

but after running cargo fmt, nothing changed.
How to apply rustfmt in this case?

The format_code_in_doc_comments option is currently unstable.  Are you using a nightly toolchain, eg cargo +nightly fmt?
